# Most optimal way to prioritize records based on bit columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016

There is a 1 to many relationship between tables GeoNames (not pictured) and GeoNameAlternateNames (shown below) by a FK GeoNameId.  Given the below structure, I want to get the alternateName value where IsPreferredName = 1, if that is not found then use the next column IsShortName, if that record isn't found then use the next column and so on and so on.  In this instance I would expect The top row to be returned.  Please keep in mind that I will be joining into this table from a GeoNames table.

There are 11 million+ records in GeoNames and 17 million+ in GeoNamesAlternateNames so going at it like a neanderthal is not an acceptable solution.

What is the best performing strategy around this?  I've tried group by, left joining on each column and coalescing, Ranking into sub tables, and I'm about to pull out my hair.  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you change the tables, i.e. add a computed column to be indexed? And are the values of all `is...` columns either `1` or `NULL` (or maybe `0`)? I assume, that `from` and `to` aren't part of the check, is that correct?

Comment: We are using sql server 2016.  I want to keep the original datasource as is and not transform the data if possible.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a prioritization query.  You want one row per `geonameid`, so use `row_number()` with an appropriate `order by` clause:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by geonameid
                                order by (case when IsPreferredName = 1 then 1
                                               when IsShortName = 1 then 2
                                               . . .
                                          end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This looks like the trick I will try it out on Monday!  Thank you!